# Result order in the Google Drive SDK

Tags: google-drive-api

Can we order a file list with the Google Drive Api (by title, kind or last update)? This obviously can't be done on the client side as we're not supposed to get the whole list in one bit but can't figure out how to order it on the server side. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no query parameters that would let a client request a sorted list of files from the Google Drive API. This is a valid feature request that we could consider.

In the meantime, client applications have no choice but to perform sorting on their side.

Comment: Thank you Alain for your answer. I think the order parameter is really a must have. Problem is you can't order the result if you don't have the whole set (as the "Load More" function would reorder the previously displayed results). Btw, the API used by drive.google.com does have this feature, so I hope you'll consider it also for the sdk :)

Comment: Does Google Drive API has a public issue tracker where we can see and follow the issues and feature requests?

Answer (score 0):

In 2022 (and probably for many years already), this is possible via the `orderBy` parameter, documented at https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list:

> A comma-separated list of sort keys. Valid keys are 'createdTime',
> 'folder', 'modifiedByMeTime', 'modifiedTime', 'name', 'name_natural',
> 'quotaBytesUsed', 'recency', 'sharedWithMeTime', 'starred', and
> 'viewedByMeTime'. Each key sorts ascending by default, but may be
> reversed with the 'desc' modifier. Example usage:
> ?orderBy=folder,modifiedTime desc,name. Please note that there is a
> current limitation for users with approximately one million files in
> which the requested sort order is ignored.